# Find minimal acceptable image quality: features

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

For some pictures, even great quality loss can be imperceptible to the human eye. For example, for small ones. However, for large pictures those artifacts might quickly become visible.

So, my goal is to find minimal value of quality, that produced artifacts will be "imperceptible" for human. Obviously, image size is one of the features, ratio `size / weight` is second, but what are another features?

My original idea was to find several features, manually create a test set and to train some machine learning tool to answer this question.

Maybe there are some researches in this area, and I'm missing some important information?

Comment: In jpeg image compression, you typically find square boxes as artifacts of compression in large, uniformly colored areas. It would be very unlikely to find natural patterns with such regularity in photos. You could detect edges from such artifacts fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, in fact, a very hot computer vision research topic - *image quality assessment*. Obviously, it seems, that you have not done background research in this area, may be because you did not know the term for this phenomenon. I would suggest you to start reading computer vision papers related to image quality assessment.